# Sharepoint 2010 Replacable Parameter not working

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have an aspx page in _layouts that is part of a package.  It contains :

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
```

This should be updated with the current assembly full name when I deploy - but it dont.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean "updated when I deploy" ? What is the expected end result ? 
How do you deploy ? A solution, a feature ? 
Could you point to the doc explaining the replacement capabilities ?

Comment: Right, so replaceable parameters are new to 2010.  In theory, you can use them in ASPX, ASCX, XML etc.  They are replaced with real values when you build/deploy the package.  Sort of like VS template macros.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231545(VS.100).aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the element needs to be included in the package - durrr. Silly me.